# warning C4752: found Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions when using _mm256_setr_epi16

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, avx, avx2

I am writing C++ program using /arch:AVX2 on visual studio 2015, and added `#include <immintrin.h>`

most AVX methods work fine, including `_mm256_setr_epi32()`

but when I try using `_mm256_setr_epi16()` I get the following error:

> warning C4752: found Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions; consider using /arch:AVX

all input parameters are short integers. I have isolated the error to the 9th to 16th parameters - when they are a const number - all is OK, but when I put a short variable in some of these places I get an error.

EDIT:
did't find a solution, but used this workaround

```
#pragma warning(disable:4752) {my method here} #pragma warning(default:4752)
```

which dismisses any warnings but compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: Odd as that is (obviously AVX is allowed when AVX2 is enabled), there really shouldn't be non-constants in a set macro most of the time in the first place (some specific patterns are ok).

Comment: Consider it both a code and performance smell to use non-constants for any set intrinsic that takes more than 2 parameters.

Comment: I put constants only as an example of error location. obviously I use non-constant parameters as input to the method

Comment: @HaimItzhayek You should *not* use non-constant parameters. If you take a look at how they get compiled, you'll see that unless all the parameters are constant, it will be very slow. That's fine if the set itself is not performance critical (like some initialization vector or something).